# Composer install issue in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, composer, php-7.2

I have one issue when I run composer install command.

[image]

How to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: are you running it on local?

Comment: your shashum in composer.lock shoud be like this `"shasum": "5301f7a4d294cabcab3ae83e31fe5386c076520c"`

Answer (score 2):

**In my composer.lock was wrong info about this and any other packages yet. I have revert my changes with composer.json / composer.lock and it works for me. You can try:**

> 1. Clear the composer cache
> 2. Remove the vendors
> 3. Change in composer.json version of packages to static (e.g 1.2.0) to avoid update of them
> 4. Remove composer.lock
> 5. Start composer install. Then it should work correclty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **vertex/module-tax shasum** value in **composer.lock** equals to this:

```
"shasum": "5301f7a4d294cabcab3ae83e31fe5386c076520c"
```

Or try to add this line in your **`composer.json`**

```
"replace": {
        "vertex/module-tax": "*"
},
```

Comment: Why we need to add this line in composer.json file?

Comment: to skip vertex module installation since it is not a required module of magento because it is a third party module not a core magento one

Comment: will it cause any issue in magento?

Comment: Nope it will not.

Comment: unless you are using it on your webshop

Answer (score 0):

It's trouble with vertex/module-tax.
Add to replace this module in your file **composer.json**

```
   "replace": {
        "vertex/module-tax": "*"
},
```

after that need use:

```
composer update
```

after a successful update, install vertex/module-tax

```
composer require vertex/module-tax
composer update
```

Comment: Why we need to add this line in composer.json file?

Comment: It's needed for delete this module. 
After successful update you can install module again.